# Publishing Research Papers on Mathematical Software Packages

Tags: reference-request, education, math-software, research, publishing

I have written some LaTeX package for Mathematics. It involves substantial work. In general only a person having good knowledge of Mathematics and TeX could develop such things. There are other pedagogical applications of work as well. I want to publish this as a research (from pedagogy point of view) in standard journals of Mathematics and /or Computer which are listed in Web of Science and/or Scopus. Are there any journals which can accept such type of work? Could anyone recommend some journals for the same? I hope the question here on this site is relevant as it deals with Mathematics Packages and its Publications.

Comment: Try https://www.tug.org/TUGboat/

Answer (score 0):

You should submit your package to [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/), the Comprehensive TEX Archive Network (CTAN). It is the central place for $\TeX$ and $\LaTeX$ packages and it currently contains over 6000 packages.